# PHP function to use prepared SQL statements - using implode to enter values of array separated by commas as arguments for function

Tags: php, sql, function, mysqli, arguments

I have recently asked some questions about security against SQL injection vulnerabilities.  I decided to make a function that would do a sql query using a prepared statement so I didn't have to write out so many lines of code for every query:

```
function secure_sql($query, $values, $datatypes){
    global $link;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    foreach($values as &$value){
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, substr($datatypes, 0), $value);
        $datatypes = substr($datatypes, -(strlen($datatypes)-1));
    }
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, implode(", ", $values));
    $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    return $results;
}
```

where query is the prepared query (with ?s), $values is an array of all the variables replacing the placeholder ?s (in order) and $datatypes is a string containing all the data types for the variables.  $link is a database connection.

So I have two main questions.

1) It is not working.  I think this must be because of implode maybe not being used correctly in this context.  What would I use instead?  I can't use call_user_func_array because I also need to have $stmt as an argument.  I have tried using array_unshift to add $stmt to the beginning of the argument, but it doesn't work.

2) If I do get it to work, what could be done to improve it?  I am still a PHP and SQL beginner.

EDIT: I have solved the problem now.  Thank you all for your helpful comments and answers!

Comment: The function mysqli_real_escape_string() is not necessary if you're using a prepared query.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for that; I'll remove it.  Do you have any idea about the array and variable being passed through to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly giving you the code I came up with, I feel that explaining it is necessary, seeing how some of your ways of thinking are rather incorrect.

Firstly, the use of `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` confuses me - your second argument expression (`substr($datatypes, 0)`) returns a value of all the datatypes, yet you are only binding one. What I think you meant to put is:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $datatypes[0] /* <-- retrieves the first character */, $value);
```

But more importantly, you should only call `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` *once*, which gives you some bigger difficulties... To omit the `foreach`-loop, how about `call_user_func_array()`? (Actually, it's very possible to keep `$stmt` as an argument):

```
call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", array_merge(array($stmt, $datatypes), $values)); 
//calls mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $datatypes, $values[0], $values[1]... values[n]);
```

If you're confused by the thing above, look at it in this way:

```
call_user_func_array             //a call to mysqli_stmt_bind_param, with all the appropriate parameters
(
   "mysqli_stmt_bind_param",     //the function to call
   array_merge                   //an array consisting of the statement, the datatype and all the values
   (
       array($stmt, $datatypes), //statement and datatype-parameters
       $values                   //all the values
   )
);
```

This does, however, require your `$values`-array to consist of references, as the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` expects your values to be so. If you still want to pass them as values into your function, you could add this, and later pass `$ref_values` into the `call_user_func_array()` function:

```
foreach ($values as &$value) $ref_values[] = &$value;
```

Now we come to the use of `implode()`, which also is incorrect. To reference from the PHP-manual:

**Implode (Return Value):**

> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

**mysqli_stmt_bind_result (Second-Nth Parameter):**

> The variable to be bound.

So what you're attempting to do here is to make a `string` returned by `implode()` a variable, which makes no sense. Although luckily, [`mysqli_stmt_get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) returns an object which is fetched after execution, meaning that the bind_result-function isn't needed. So try removing that line.

In all, I would re-write the code like this:

```
function secure_sql($query, $values, $datatypes) {
    global $link;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    foreach ($values as &$value) $ref_values[] = &$value;
    call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", array_merge(array($stmt, $datatypes), $ref_values));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    return mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
}
```

To me, it sounds like that should work, but if it doesn't, tell me (I might be missing something or thinking incorrectly somewhere).

To answer the second question, it all looks good, except that I wouldn't advice you to use `mysqli_`-functions, as they will get removed eventually (as said in the [PHP-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)). If you're planning to use objects instead, most of it is similar when it comes to my changes (apart from the fact that you need to use object-properties and object-methods with them instead...), except the `call_user_func_array()` function. Luckily though, calling a method with it is possible as well, by specifying an array as the first parameter, consisting of the object and the method name (`call_user_func_array($prepared_obj, "bind_param") ...)`).

**Edit:** Considering how necessary it is, I made a function that does the same thing, but works on an mysqli object instead:

```
function secure_sql($query, $values, $datatypes) {
    global $mysqli_object; //declared with $mysql_object = new mysqli(...)
    $stmt = $mysqli_object->prepare($query);
    foreach ($values as &$value) $ref_values[] = &$value;
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($datatypes), $ref_values));
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer.  If I had 4 more rep, I would definitely vote it up.

Comment: @user3430472 No problems. If it works, you can always accept it to mark so, by the way (though maybe you haven't tried it yet, and maybe you knew this). Just saying, just in case. Anyhow, figuring how important the object-version of this is, I'll add that version to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm personally a sucker for procedural style, but I understand its benefits.  I have one question: I am returning mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)), but if the query is unsuccessful I get mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.  If I put an if statement into the function (if mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) !== false), then I get invalid argument supplied for foreach.  Is there any way I can really deal with this error (I know it's not really a problem and I know I can stop error reporting)

Comment: @user3430472 Apparently, get_result returns `false`, which means that it fails. I have tried the code I've posted, and everything works fine for me. Can you post the function call? Have you made any other modifications to the code? (PS: Procedural style is the one you're using now. The other is called object-orientated style)

Comment: function secure_mysqli($query, $values, $datatypes) {
    global $link;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    foreach ($values as &$value) $ref_values[] = &$value;
    call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", array_merge(array($stmt, $datatypes), $ref_values));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt));
}

Comment: sorry, I didn't realise it would format so badly.  The only modification is the return statement.  It returns an array of mysqli_fetch_assoc; mysqli_fetch_assoc does not like false as a value (obviously); then comes the error.  Or an error in other foreach statements (outside the function).  I was just wondering how to solve them.  Thanks.  Sorry if this isn't too clear

Comment: @user3430472 Oh, it's okay. But are you certain that the query and all the parameters in the function call works properly? If not sure, can you perhaps send them?

Comment: No all that works fine.  So it's not really a problem (I can disable error reporting if necessary) but I was just wondering if there were an easy solution

Comment: Well, if get_result returns false, then there must be something going wrong, really. Not sure how `mysqli_fetch_assoc` works with `mysqli_stmt_get_result`, but perhaps you can try using `mysqli_stmt_get_result(...)->fetch_array()` instead? Other than that, check that your query is valid to your table, that your connection with the database works properly, etc. I would move this to a chat discussion, but it seems like you can't chat yet (due to your current reputation).

Comment: Sorry, n00b question: how would that be in procedural style

Comment: It is still procedural style - procedural/object-style only refers to `mysqli` functions (in your case, that is), while this is a simple property of the returned object. You can use the method above without worrying about procedural style.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that.  It doesn't appear to make a difference to the error messages but, as I have said, they are unimportant

Comment: @user3430472 It's your choice, really. If it works, it works (personally I would trace it though). Also, if you want to save other people some time from answering this question again when it's answered already, you can mark the answer as accepted. Although only do that if it really works - now it sort of sounds like it doesn't :P